# Custom JSON serialization with Jersey 2.x/MOXy

Tags: moxy, jersey-2.0

Im using Jersey 2.x with built in MOXy conversion from JSON<-->POJO inside of an embedded Jetty 9.x server.

Is it possible to define a custom JSON (de)serialization routine for specific types (e.g. Joda DateTime) programmatically (without annotations on the POJO) - if so, how?

Currently I've got the following code for configuring Jersey with my embedded Jetty server instance:

```
    ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
    resourceConfig.packages( "com.company.app.rest.v1" );
    resourceConfig.register( new GZipEncoder() );
    resourceConfig.register( new LoggingFilter() );
    ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder( new ServletContainer( resourceConfig ) );

    context.addServlet( servletHolder, "/rest/v1/*" );
```

and its working fine for simple POJOs - I just want to be able to customize the (de)serialization.  Is there a way to plugin converters for specific types, along the lines of:

```
registerTypeConverter( MySpecificType.class, CustomReader.class, CustomWriter.class );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in [this wiki article](https://github.com/jasonray/jersey-starterkit/wiki/Serializing-a-POJO-to-xml-or-json-using-JAXB). Most of it deals with XML serialization, but at the bottom you'll find how to customize JSON serialization.

Basically you create a custom `ContextResolver<JAXBContext>` which returns a custom `JSONJAXBContext` which in turn has a custom `JSONConfiguration`. Don't forget to annotate it with `@Provider` (and register it in your Application if necessary). I'll copy the example code for completeness, you never know how long these things survive :)

```
@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext context;
    private Class[] types = { Address.class, Customer.class, CustomerResource.class };

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().build(), types);
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        for (Class type : types) {
            if (type == objectType) {
                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```